# Android Studio Kotlin File Read

Tags: android, kotlin, file

Hey i have this working FileWrite routine which i can simply call with

```
writeFile("Filename as String","Filetext as String")
```

but i cant read back the File i tried many solutions. I just want to call the read routine like this:
readFile("Filename as String") and file data should go to Sting: "txtfromfile"

```
`fun writeFile(name : String, data : String) {
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Sunny/")
    }

    val extVolumeUri: Uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")


    // query for the file
    val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
        extVolumeUri,
        null,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?",
        arrayOf(name, "text/plain"),
        null
    )

    var fileUri: Uri? = null

    // if file found
    if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0) {
        // get URI
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            if (nameIndex > -1) {
                val displayName = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                if (displayName == name) {
                    val idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
                    if (idIndex > -1) {
                        val id = cursor.getLong(idIndex)
                        fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(extVolumeUri, id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cursor.close()
    } else {
        // insert new file otherwise
        fileUri = contentResolver.insert(extVolumeUri, contentValues)
    }

    if (fileUri != null) {
        val os = contentResolver.openOutputStream(fileUri, "wt")

        if (os != null) {
            os.write(data.toByteArray())
            os.close()
        }
    }
}`
```

i tryed numerous read Routines
But I can't find any that I can call like my write routine

Comment: What have you tried? Could you get an `InputStream` for your file at least?

Answer (score 0):

i tried this but it gives me "java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

```
fun readFile(name : String) {
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Sunny/")
    }

    val extVolumeUri: Uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")

    var fileUri: Uri? = null

    fileUri = contentResolver.insert(extVolumeUri, contentValues)


    val os = fileUri?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }

    if (os != null) {
        txtfromfile = os.read().toString()
        os.close()
    }

}
```

Comment: ok this works:fun readFile(name: String) {
        val inputStream: InputStream = File("storage/emulated/0/Documents/Sunny/"+name).inputStream()
        txtfromfile = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    }